# Display -only One property object- among many properties objec where objects are wrapped in array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Please Help, I just started to read angularJS

I have a ojects with keys like

```
scope.eventList=[];
for(){
             var event = {
                         id          : hash,
                         title       : title,
                         url         : 'http://www.xxxxx.com/',
                         start       : start,
                         end         : end,
                         allDay      : false,
                         location    : '',
                         description : '',
                         editable    : true
                        };

                 $scope.eventList.push(event); 

}
```

which gives an eventList (array of objects):

```
[
 {
                         id          : hash,
                         title       : "TITLE1" ,
                         url         : 'https://www.xxxxx.com/',
                         start       : start,
                         end         : end,
                         allDay      : false,
                         location    : '',
                         description : '',
                         editable    : true
 },
{
                         id          : hash,
                         title       : "TITLE2" ,
                         url         : 'https://www.xxxxx.com/',
                         start       : start,
                         end         : end,
                         allDay      : false,
                         location    : '',
                         description : '',
                         editable    : true
}
]
```

I need to put this into an ng-repeat but only show the item's titles

```
like : Title1
       Title2
       Title3
       ......
       TitleN
```

Tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
 <div customEventName="{{item.title}}" 
     ng-model="item" ng-repeat="item.title in eventList track by $index">
     {{item.title}}
    </div>
```

Many thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `ng-model` neither `track by $index` in your case.

Your issue is that the `Y` of the `Y in X` inside `ng-repeat` is the "target" variable that will contain the current item contained in the array `X`.

The correct code is then:

```
<div
  ng-repeat="item in eventList"
  customEventName="{{item.title}}">
  {{item.title}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
data = [
 {
   id : 'hash',
   title : "TITLE1" ,
   url : 'https://www.xxxxx.com/',
   start: 'start',
   end : 'end',
                  
 },
  {
   id : 'hash',
   title : "TITLE2" ,
   url : 'https://www.xxxxx.com/',
   start: 'start',
   end : 'end',
                  
 }, {
   id : 'hash',
   title : "TITLE3" ,
   url : 'https://www.xxxxx.com/',
   start: 'start',
   end : 'end',
                  
 },

]

var titles = data.map(({title})=> title)
console.log(titles)
```